# Set ObjectMeta on Istio-resource with go-client

Tags: go, kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-go-client

I'm trying to work with Istio from Go, and are using Kubernetes and Istio go-client code.

The problem I'm having is that I can't specify `ObjectMeta` or `TypeMeta` in my Istio-`ServiceRole` object. I can only specify `rules`, which are inside the `spec`.

Below you can see what I got working:

```golang
import (
    v1alpha1 "istio.io/api/rbac/v1alpha1"
)


func getDefaultServiceRole(app nais.Application) *v1alpha1.ServiceRole {
    return &v1alpha1.ServiceRole{
        Rules: []*v1alpha1.AccessRule{
            {
                Ports: []int32{2},
            },
        },
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have this code work:

```golang
func getDefaultServiceRole(app *nais.Application) *v1alpha1.ServiceRole {
    return &v1alpha1.ServiceRole{
        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       "ServiceRole",
            APIVersion: "v1alpha1",
        },
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      app.Name,
            Namespace: app.Namespace,
        },
        Spec: v1alpha1.ServiceRole{
            Rules: []*v1alpha1.AccessRule{
                {
                    Ports: []int32{2},
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah - this is a pretty painful point: Istio requires Kubernetes CRD wrapper metadata (primarily the `name` and `namespace` fields), but those fields are not part of the API objects themselves nor are they represented in the protos. (This is changing with the new MCP API for configuring components - which Galley uses - [does encode these fields as protobufs](https://github.com/istio/api/blob/master/mcp/v1alpha1/metadata.proto) but that doesn't help for your use case.) Instead, you should use the types in [`istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/config/kube/crd`](https://godoc.org/istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/config/kube/crd), which implement the K8s CRD interface.

The easiest way to work with the Istio objects in golang is to use Pilot's libraries, particularly the [`istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/model`](https://godoc.org/istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/model) and [`istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/config/kube/crd`](https://godoc.org/istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/config/kube/crd) packages, as well as the [`model.Config`](https://godoc.org/istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/model#Config) struct. You can either pass around the full `model.Config` (not great because `spec` has type `proto.Message` so you need type assertions to extract the data you care about), or pass around the inner object wrap it in a `model.Config` before you push it. You can use the [`model.ProtoSchema`](https://godoc.org/istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/model#ProtoSchema) type to help with conversion to and from YAML and JSON. [Pilot only defines `ProtoSchema` objects for the networking API](https://godoc.org/istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/model#pkg-variables), the type is public and you can create them for arbitrary types.

So, using your example code I might try something like:

```golang
import (
    v1alpha1 "istio.io/api/rbac/v1alpha1"
   "istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/model"
)


func getDefaultServiceRole() *v1alpha1.ServiceRole {
    return &v1alpha1.ServiceRole{
        Rules: []*v1alpha1.AccessRule{
            {
                Ports: []int32{2},
            },
        },
    }
}

func toConfig(app *nais.Application, role *v1alpha1.ServiceRole) model.Config {
    return &model.Config{
        ConfigMeta: model.ConfigMeta{
            Name:      app.Name,
            Namespace: app.Namespace,
        },
        Spec: app,
    }
}

type Client model.ConfigStore
func (c Client) CreateRoleFor(app nais.Application, role *v1alpha1.ServiceRole) error {
    cfg := toConfig(app, role)
    _, err := c.Create(cfg)
    return err
}
```

As a more complete example, we built the Istio CloudMap operator in this style. [Here's the core of it that pushes config to K8s with Pilot libraries.](https://github.com/tetratelabs/istio-cloud-map/blob/master/pkg/control/synchronizer.go#L64-L91) Here's [the incantation to create an instance of model.ConfigStore to use to create objects](https://github.com/tetratelabs/istio-cloud-map/blob/e3c95237f5e0743f9ec9898fdf1809321df91b5e/pkg/control/synchronizer.go#L28). Finally, I want to call out explicitly as it's only implicit in the example: when you call `Create` on the `model.ConfigStore`, the `ConfigStore` relies on the metadata in the `ProtoSchema` objects used to create it. So be sure to initialize the store with `ProtoSchema` objects for all of the types you'll be working with.

---

You can achieve the same using just the K8s client libraries and the `istio.io/istio/pilot/pkg/config/kube/crd` package, but I have not done it firsthand and don't have examples handy.

Answer (score 4):

Istio now supports:

```
import (
    istiov1alpha3 "istio.io/api/networking/v1alpha3"
    istiogov1alpha3 "istio.io/client-go/pkg/apis/networking/v1alpha3"
)

VirtualService := istiogov1alpha3.VirtualService{
        TypeMeta:   metav1.TypeMeta{
            Kind: "VirtualService",
            APIVersion: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3",
        },
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "my-name",
        },
        Spec:       istiov1alpha3.VirtualService{},
}
```

Where `istiov1alpha3.VirtualService{}` is an istio object.